# Trying to create a login system with PHP and MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've started learning a bit of MYSQLi & PHP today, but I am kinda stuck at this point. I've tried several methods but nothing seems to work for me since I don't really understand much of it. I'm trying to create the ability to login for a user that has an account already, but it doesn't seem te work.

Also, I'm aware that my current password encryption is weak, but I'm just trying to learn the basics first before I'm getting deeper into security issue's.

Anyways, here is my code:

**Form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php" name="login">
Email <input type="email" name="email">
Password <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

**PHP:**
    require_once('core/init.php'); // connect to the database through new mysqli

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['user'] != ''){
    header('Location: profile.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['password'] );

    $hash = md5($password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$hash'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if( $num_row == 1 ) {
        echo "Does work";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['id'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Does not work.";
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: so what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: @castis it doesn't give any response within the if( $num_row == 1) statement.

Comment: I would echo $query and see what it has built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the DB connection parameter to your POST arrays 
`mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $var)` which you are not doing and is ***required***, while making sure that all your form elements hold a matching name attribute, including a POST method.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

*From the manual:*

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Plus, I suggest you add `exit;` after header. Otherwise, code may continue executing.

Your conditional statement

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

doesn't match your submit button input

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which should be named "submit" instead of "login"

Anything inside that conditional statement will ***not*** be executed.

Change it to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick comment. I've edited the escape string, but it didn't seem te be the problem. I enabled error reporting and it gave me this message: `Notice: Undefined index: user in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wetravel/login.php on line 8` which seems to be the $_SESSION['user']

Comment: @user2962542 I spotted something else after you did an edit. I will edit my answer with something else.

Comment: @user2962542 Give me a few more minutes. I'll add a few more things. I'll let you know once I've done the edit in accordance with the error you got about "user".

Comment: @user2962542 If you haven't previously defined the session array, then that would be the cause of it. Other than that, it's best to use `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){...}` instead of `if($_SESSION['user'] != '')` if the session array/variable has been defined. If not, then you will need to define it.

Comment: Thank you, you're awesome. Everything seems to be working now since I get redirected to profile.php.

Comment: @user2962542 You're very much welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

check this links

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website--net-2853

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-better-login-system--net-3461

i hope for help

Comment: Although this links may answer the question, please post relevant part answering the OP question here, remembering a link can go outdated and or broken.